# Set <img> src to url in Yii2 mail

Tags: php, email, yii, yii2

I am working on a project in `Yii 2.0`. I have to send email to the users with an `<img>` tag with `"src"` attribute set to a url that points to an action on my server (for tracking of email, to check if user has opened it). I am doing this:

```
$message = \Yii::$app->mail->compose()
                        ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => $usersurveyconfig->survey_email_from])
                        ->setTo($customers->email)
                        ->setSubject($usersurveyconfig->survey_email_subject);

$imageFileName = "http://www.myserver.com/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/myaction";
<img src="<?= $message->embed($imageFileName) ?>">
```

But when I send email, this error pops up:

> Unable to open file for reading
>   [http://www.myserver.com/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/myaction]

So, How can I achieve this? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is for tracking purposes, then you shouldn't embed it. Thus your code should be:

```
<img src="<?= $imageFileName ?>">
```

For embedding, the parameter should be the path to the file to embed e.g

```
<img src="<?= $message->embed('../web/images/image.png') ?>">
```

See [the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-message.html#embed()-detail) for more information.